# Detecting Which Browser In Java gwt

Tags: java, google-chrome, browser, mozilla

i'am developping appplication java and i want to know which browser is opened when i launche application?

i found abstract class in gwt Browser :

```
 package com.google.gwt.query.client;
```

import com.google.gwt.query.rebind.BrowserGenerator;

/**
 * This class is the equivalent to the jQuery.browser object in gQuery.
 * 
 * The implementation is performed by the {@link BrowserGenerator}
 * 
 * It can be used as a way of deferred-binding without modifying .gwt.xml files,
 * taking advantage of compiler optimizations which will or will not include the
 * code in a 'if' statement checking these conditions.
 * 
 * Example:
 *

```
      if (GQuery.browser.ie6) {
        // this code will be removed on non-ie6 permutations 
        Window.alert("IE6");
      } else if (!browser.webkit) {
        // this code will be only in the webkit permutation 
        Window.alert("NOT WEBKIT");
      } 
 *
```

*
 */
public abstract class Browser {

but i don't khnow how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

You can found the user agent by using the native java script

```
 public static native String getUserAgent() /*-{
      return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
}-*/;
```

You can find the user agent using

```
Window.Navigator.getUserAgent();
```

Comment: When i use the condition if(Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().contains("firefox")){///}else if(Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().contains("chrome")){///} it's not working and the application crashes

Comment: com.google.gwt.user.client.Winow.Navigator.getUserAgent() will return the user-agent String.  Refer http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html                                                                                       Otherwise. use the native js method to detect the user-agent.